# Apache clean url with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect

**http://example.com/post.php?id=1**

to

**http://example.com/post/1**

Tried alot but either the redirect is not working, or redirecting to wrong url.

Sample Htaccess Code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/post\.php\?id=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ post/%1 [R,L]
```

- When using **RewriteBase /** it redirects to wrong url, like http://example.com/C:/wamp64/www/project/post/1

Comment: Then don't use the RewriteBase? // And the "not working" description needs to be qualified with access *and* rewrite log.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not possible to include query params in a RewriteCond using REQUEST_URI. The following config can be used to check for query params:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} post.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)
RewriteRule post.php post/%1? [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this will only work if i add RewriteBase / after RewriteEngine On. Without adding RewriteBase /, whenever i visit http://example.com/post.php?id=1 it redirects to http://example.com/C:/wamp64/www/project/post/1 . Any way to make it work without adding RewriteBase.

Comment: Updated the answer to only rewrite a part of the url and not the entire url. @Kim